# FilenameFilter for several files

Tags: java, filenames

I have a folder where excel files are stored. The files always start with Template HP_x.xlsx (x stands for additional information). With a loop I have already read the path and the name of the file. Unfortunately it reads out all xlsx files. How can I use the filenamefilter so that it only reads out the Template_HP...xlsx files?

Thank you :).

Answer (score 2):

You could check the start of the filename and the extension, something like this:

```java
... new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        boolean checkStart = filename.toLowerCase().startsWith("Template_HP_");
        boolean checkEnd = filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xlsx");
        return (checkStart && checkEnd);
    }
} ...
```

Or, optimized..

```java
... return ((filename.toLowerCase().startsWith("Template_HP_")) && (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xlsx"))); ...
```

The code just checks if the string containing the filename starts with `Template_HP_` and ends with the correct extension, `.xlsx`.
If so, it returns true, otherwise false.

Comment: There's a `.` missing before `endsWith` in both code snippets.

Comment: @Izruo thanks, didn't notice! I corrected it.